# Discord.py - messages for users with more roles

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted my bot to write a message to users, who have two or more specific roles, not just one part of those.

The code is here (without the token):

```
import discord 
import asyncio
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author

    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="2A") and member.roles=="1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D"
   if role in message.author.roles and message.content == "test":
     await message.channel.send("response")
   else:
     return

   role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="3A") and member.roles=="1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D"
   if role in message.author.roles and message.content == "test":
       await message.channel.send("response")
   else:
        return
```

but it doesn't react in any way.
Is it even possible to program something like this?

Comment: your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to respond when the user just has more then 1 roles in number or is it like if the user has more then 1 roles from some specific roles?

Comment: I want my bot to respond if a User has 2 roles from some specific roles.

Answer (score 0):

So you can make a much easier solution than just getting every single role with saving the names. **I'd rather do this with IDs as they're always the same**

Then you can delete the `member` variable as it is pretty useless (you are just shortening a short name)

And then check through all roles the user has to see if any of them is in the name list (and the content is "test").

**EDIT:** You have to double-check the roles as you want to know if there are two roles of the `role_names` in the roles, also you can move the `if message.content ...` to the top to save going through all roles everytime a message is sent

If some role is in the name list you have to `break` the `for loop` and continue doing the stuff you do afterwards (if there is no stuff afterwards you can also delete the `else: return`)

Finally looks like this:

```py
import discord 
import asyncio

role_names = ["1B", "1C", "1D", "1E", "1F", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D", "2E", "2F", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E", "3F", "4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "4E", "4F", "5A", "5B", "5C", "5D", "6A", "6B", "6C", "6D", "7A", "7B", "7C", "7D", "8A", "8B", "8C", "8D"]

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test":
        role1 = None
        for role in message.author.roles:
            if role.name in role_names:
                role1 = role
            if role1 is not None and role.name in role_names and role.name != role1.name:
            # Check if role1 is found and role has another role name and is a right role
                await message.channel.send("response")
                break
```

Comment: I tried to run the code, but I am getting this error: `NameError: name 'role2' is not defined`

Comment: Oh sorry I was a bit confused as the second role came in.. edited the answer, should hopefully work now

Comment: Well, no error message this time, but it doesn't respond

Comment: Try to debug it (adding `print()` after and before important lines) as I can't see anything wrong here (also make sure you got the 2 Roles of the Roles in `role_names` and their name is identical to the in `role_names`)